# Android keyboard with correct or configurable button placement

Tags: android, keyboard

Here ia a standard keyboard button layout.

[image]

Here is how it is in my current (SAMSUNG) keyboard.

[image]

Notice the bottom two rows are exactly above one another, rather than slightly shifted, as in a standard computer keyboard as above.

For example, in a standard keyboard, 'z' should not be directly under 's', but between 'a' and 's'.

This offset causes typos.

In other, non latin languages, it gets worse, as the developers don't even know the standard.

---

Is there a keyboard app in which the user can edit the button locations?

What is the technical term for what I am looking for? It isn't "keyboard layout" which finds results such as QWERTY vs other.